# How can I add methods to a class and use them in a for-style loop of its super class?

Tags: java, oop, generics

Say I have a generic array like this:

```
ArrayList<Fruit>  fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
```

Then I add lots of different fruits, which all extends the class fruit, and loop through them

```
for (Fruit f : fruits) {

}
```

If the fruit is a banana, I want to check how round it is, so..

```
for (Fruit f : fruits) {
    if (f instanceof Bannana)
        f.checkHowRoundBannanaIs();
}
```

I will have to put the `checkHowRoundBannnaIs()` method in the fruit class, even though the fruit may not be a banana, because I can't use the function on f if it isn't in the fruit class, otherwise I get a undefined method error (or something like that).

This is fine for one or two methods, but after a while it makes the class bulky and ugly. So my question is, how can I add methods to a class and use them in a for-style loop of its super class?

Comment: The examples are written in Java, but it isn't a Java problem.

Comment: Right. This problem is common to all languages with a single dispatch mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***So my question is, how can I add methods to a class and use them in a for-style loop of its super class?***

Short answer, you can't really.

If you want to call the methods in the body of the for-loop, `instanceof` and down-casting is the only way I can think of:

```
for (Fruit f : fruits) {
    if (f instanceof Banana)
        ((Banana) f).checkHowRoundBananaIs();
    // ...
}
```

---

Both `instanceof` and down-casting are usually considered bad practice though. To avoid it, you could implement the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Here are the steps you would need to take:

1. Create a visitor interface like this:

   ```
   interface FruitVisitor {
       void visit(Banana banana);
       void visit(Apple apple);
   }
   ```
2. Let all fruits *accept* a visitor:

   ```
   abstract class Fruit {
       // ...
       public abstract void accept(FruitVisitor fv);
   }

   class Banana extends Fruit {
       public void accept(FruitVisitor fv) {
           fv.visit(this);
       }

       public void checkHowRoundBananaIs() { ... }
   }
   ```
3. Create a visitor that takes the appropriate action for each type of fruit, and pass it as argument to the `accept` method of each fruit in your list:

   ```
   FruitVisitor fv = new FruitVisitor() {
       public void visit(Banana banana) {
           banana.checkHowRoundBananaIs();
       }

       public void visit(Apple apple) {
           // ...
       }
   };

   for (Fruit f : fruits)
       f.accept(fv);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The technique most similar to what you tried there would be to cast `f` as a `Banana`:

```
if(f instanceof Bannana)
    ((Banana)f).checkHowRoundBannanaIs()
```

I'm not sure whether this is really what you want or not though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put `checkHowRoundBanannaIs()` in the `Fruit` class.  Once you know that `f` is an instance of `Banana` you can safely down-cast `f` to the type `Banana`.  Now that you have a `Banana` instance, you can call any `Banana` specific method (including `checkHowRoundBananaIs()`.

```
for(final Fruit f : fruits)
{
    if(f instanceof Banana)
    {
        final Banana b = (Banana) f;
        b.checkHowRoundBananaIs();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you are already checking if it's a banana, you could cast it to a banana then do the check..

```
for(fruit f : fruits)
{
    if(f instanceof Banana) {
        Banana b = (Banana)f;
        b.checkHowRoundBananaIs()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(fruit f : fruits)
{
  if(f instanceof Bannana)
      f.checkHowRoundBannanaIs()
}
```

... that is NOT a "for-style loop of its super class". Logically speaking.

ASA you do `instanceof Bannana` you have to import `Bannana` (though I suppose you wanted to type Banana instead). Once imported, there is no reason not to cast `f` to `Banana`. One you do that you have access to all methods of `Banana`.

In short, usually you don't do `obj1 instanceof XXX` check unless you actually want to use `obj1` as `XXX`.

Of course there are better ways like the visitor pattern (see other posts) or extracting the function to super class. Though I guess you have accepted that you have some problem with design and you don't wanna fix it.